# Use of undeclared identifier SSL_ERROR_WANT_CLIENT_HELLO_CB

Tags: openssl

I am getting an error compiling a code base that has an identifier SSL_ERROR_WANT_CLIENT_HELLO_CB.

There are also errors that member functions SSL_read_ex and SSL_write_ex are not present in the global namespace.

I tried installing OpenSSL on my system, but that idd not resolve the simple issue.

I expected this to be a simple issue that could be fixed by adding OpenSSL to the system, but supported libraries do not resolve the issue.

I also tried uninstalling OpenSSL@3 and installing OpenSSL@1.1 to fix the issue, that did not solve the problem.

Anoy suggestions how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think your include directory is not set correctly, in macOS, I ran this:

```
cd /usr/local/include/openssl
grep "SSL_ERROR_WANT_CLIENT_HELLO_CB" *
```

And added this in `ssl.h`:

```
#define SSL_ERROR_WANT_CLIENT_HELLO_CB 11
```

It means my OpenSSL include directory can provide this identifier. Try the same thing on your machine to verify whether it's something to do directory setting.